# vue3: how to combine multiple computes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

How to combine multiple compute value, like use functions, every compute value has get and set properties, and the code is too long.

```
<template>
<input v-model="equipmentCode" size="50" style="width: 200px" />
<input v-model="equipmentName" size="50" />
<input v-model="classification" size="50" />

</template>

<script>

const itemData = ref({}); // data get from server
const newData = ref({});
const props = defineProps({
    id: {}
});
let equipmentCode = computed({
    get: () => {
        return props.id ? itemData.value.equipmentCode : newData.value.equipmentCode;
    },
    set: (newValue) => {
        return props.id ? (itemData.value.equipmentCode = newValue) : (newData.value.equipmentCode = newValue);
    },
});
let equipmentName = computed({
    get: () => {
        return props.id ? itemData.value.equipmentName : newData.value.equipmentName;
    },
    set: (newValue) => {
        return props.id ? (itemData.value.equipmentName = newValue) : (newData.value.equipmentName = newValue);
    },
});
let classification = computed({
    get: () => {
        return props.id ? itemData.value.classification : newData.value.classification;
    },
    set: (newValue) => {
        return props.id ? (itemData.value.classification = newValue) : (newData.value.classification = newValue);
    },
});
</script>
```

Is there any way to combine these computes to reduce codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use your data directly?

```
const formData = props.id ? itemData : newData;
```

Otherwise:

A rule of thumb - if you can use `reactive` instead of `ref/computed` - check whether it works better.

```
const formData = reactive({... props.id ? itemData.value : newData.value});
watch(formData, () => props.id ? itemData.value = {...formData} : newData = {...formData});
```

Comment: Thanks, got understand that no need to use computed.